# Issue in unreal engine compiling in visual studio

Tags: dllexport, unreal-engine5, carla

the compiling of unreal engine files starts in visual studio and at end give me 12 errors
(E1393: a member of a class declared with dllexport/dllimport cannot itself be declared with such a specifier
E2487: SpillCellID: member of dll interface class may not be declared with dll interface).

Can you please guide me how to resolve this issue?

I am trying to install carla but for that in the compiling of unreal engine files starts in visual studio the error occurs